# Content loader reverse cursor order

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have a simple chat application. I am using content loaders to display messages inside a channel. Since I want 100 recent messages I sort messages based on the time stamp desc and limit it to 100. but I want to display recent messages at the bottom of the screen. Right now the cursor adaptor displays recent message first. How do I reverse the order of the cursor ?
According to me, I will have to write some smart query inside content provider or somehow have to manipulate the cursor inside cursor adaptor's bindView.

Comment: If you are retrieving data from a list you can simply reverse it using `Collections.reverse(array);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably use subquery

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY timestamp WHERE _id 
   IN (SELECT _id FROM table ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 100)
```

To use that with content provider:

```
String sel = BaseColumns._ID + " IN (SELECT " + BaseColumns._ID + 
  " FROM " + MyDb.TableName._TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + 
  MyDb.TableName.TIMESTAMP + " DESC LIMIT 100)";

Cursor q = getContentResolver().query(MyDb.TableName.CONTENT_URI,  
  null, sel, null, MyDb.TableName.TIMESTAMP);
```

*MyDb* is yours class defining tables and its fields, UriS etc.

Comment: How do I write such subquery with content providers ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to sort your messages based on timestamp `ASC` instead of `DESC`.

edit: Sorry, didn't grasp the subtility here.
You can try something like this to get data in reverse order:

```
for (cursor.moveToLast(); !cursor.isBeforeFirst(); cursor.moveToPrevious()) 
{
    // do your magic 
}
```

Comment: Since I am using cursor adaptor, I cant run a for a loop like that